# Symfony 2 assets:install not working

Tags: php, symfony, vagrant, assets, symlink

I'm working on vagrant with Debian and Symfony 2.8.2. I have problem with command **assets:install**. Unfortunatelly  after typed this command (I tried from Windows and Debian after logging by ssh) and I can see only:

> php app/console assets:install web/
>
> Installing assets as hard copies.

or

> php app/console assets:install --symlink
>
> Trying to install assets as absolute symbolic links.

And nothing happend even after 15 minutes and response doesn't display.

Before I was working with this project (doesn't have many files, just I am starting with this project) on Windows and Wamp and always worked fine. Any Ideas?

Other commands look quiet well, include i.e. **cache:clear**. Really I don't have any idea what is wrong.

Btw. other problem which I encountered during working on Vagrant is fact, that my antivirus (NOD) blocks Vagrant and I have to turn off antivirus firewall or not working. I am sure that during testing **assets:install** I had AV turned off. Command cache:clear worked too so I guess that AV firewall is not a problem.

**UPDATE**
**Permissions**

```
> vendor  
total 13  
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  183 lut  4 21:38 autoload.php*  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 gru  3 17:29 behat/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 gru 12 21:16 braincrafted/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 gru  2 17:57 cocur/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 lut  4 21:30 composer/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 gru  9 23:29 craue/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 lut  4 21:30 doctrine/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 lis 30 23:01 fresh/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 gru 27 16:51 friendsofsymfony/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 lut  4 21:30 gedmo/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 lut  4 21:30 genemu/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 sty 25 20:19 imagine/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 lis 28 19:34 incenteev/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 gru 20 23:24 ircmaxell/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 lis 28 19:34 jdorn/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 gru 12 21:40 jquery/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 gru  9 23:29 knplabs/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 lis 28 19:34 kriswallsmith/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 sty 25 20:19 liip/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 lis 28 19:34 monolog/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 sty 25 20:18 ocramius/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 lut  4 21:30 paragonie/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 lis 28 19:34 psr/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 gru 20 22:20 sensio/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 lis 28 19:34 sensiolabs/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 gru  9 23:29 sonata-project/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 lut  4 21:30 stof/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 lis 28 19:34 swiftmailer/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 sty 25 20:18 symfony/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 gru 12 21:40 twbs/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 lut  4 21:30 twig/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 gru 27 16:51 willdurand/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 sty 25 20:18 zendframework/


web  
total 43  
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1218 lut  1 21:46 app_dev.php*  
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10784 lis 28 19:30 apple-touch-icon.png*  
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1014 lis 28 19:30 app.php*  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 gru 13 12:38 assets/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 lut  4 22:34 bundles/  
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  5746 gru 27 16:52 config.php*  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 gru 16 23:38 css/  
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  6518 lis 28 19:30 favicon.ico*  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 gru 13 12:41 fonts/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 gru 12 22:21 images/  
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 gru 12 22:21 js/  
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   106 lis 28 19:30 robots.txt*
```

**UPDATE 2**

I discovered that it works (quite well) unless, prior to entering the command `assets:install` will remove the folder `web/bundles` manually.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does passing `-vvv` to command (e.g. `php app/console assets:install --symlink -vvv`) give any additional information?

Comment: Did you install symfony on vagrant shared files?
Unfortunatelly you must have to move that files to not synced folders, and you can use smth like deployemnt in phpstorm to update your project on vagrant.

Comment: @AurelijusRozenas I forgot about `-vvv`. I am in working now. I'll check this after work and I'll write.

Comment: @AndrzejPiszczek What You mean saying _install symfony_? I have all project files (folder root project) on bagrant shared files. In this way I am working with vagrant in my work so it's not a problem I guess. Other commands like `cache:clear` work fine.. Syncing files ok too - I can see changes in web browser.

Comment: @user2946533
I mean there could be a problem with a large number of copying files when you install assets, and for sure --symlink will not work on windows.

I've installed many symfony projects on vagrant but never on synced files (when i did that whole application run extremally slow, even if i move cache folder away from syncing)

Comment: @user2946533
My workflow looks that:
I have PhpStorm on Windows and all project files with initialized repository.
PhpStorm has configured deployment updating to vagrant
Every time if i change something in files -> phpstorm automatically update it to vagrant machine (where is true running project).
Every command except git commands, I typing on vagrant machine through ssh conneciton. 
It's seems little bit complicated but it working very well (a significantly faster than synced files) and it is very usefull.

Comment: @user2946533

Backing to the topic:

There could be problem with save many files on synced folders (like web) on your host machine (windows).

I'm using puphpet to generate all needed stuff. There is my own puphet file (with usefull command like, debug on/off, which on/off xdebug)
https://github.com/dzordzan/vagrant
sorry for my english :)

Comment: @AndrzejPiszczek I totally understand Your concept now. At the end I can try this way, but I preffer automatically updateing files by vagrant. I am working in this way in my work (windows + vagrant) and it's working fine.

After Your answer I guess that problem causes `xdebug on`. In work I have `xdebug off`, but it's only my guess. I'll check this.

Comment: @AndrzejPiszczek I discovered that it works (quite well) unless, prior to entering the command `assets:install` will remove the folder `web/bundles` manually.